# Gifsicle change frame delay of every 3rd frame

Tags: gif

I have a series of gifs with a delay of 0.02 secs, I want to change the delay to 2-2-1:

0.02

0.02

0.01

where every 3rd frame is 0.01 secs

I know I can edit specific frames

```
gifsicle -b original.gif -d50 "#0" "#1" -d100 "#2" "#3"
```

But not sure how to step through every 3rd frame to make it 0.01 secs

Comment: Sounds like a question for the creators/maintainers of the library you're using